# Maximum number of dimensions in Nvidia HPC compiler

Tags: fortran, nvidia, hpc, nvidia-hpc-compilers

Does anyone know what the maximum number of dimensions is for the Nvidia HPC compiler for `Fortran`?

It used to be 7, but a thread in 2019 said they were working on adding it. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/more-than-seven-dimensions-specified-for-array/136072

Comment: If you can't find the number in the documentation, have you tried to compile something like `dimension x(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1); end`?

Comment: Nvidia/PGI will know. Why not ask them?

Comment: What's wrong with asking this question on StackOverflow? Even if the OP can find the answer in 1000 other places and forums, they decided to ask the shared wisdom of StackOverflow. There is no need to force them never to return to Stackoverflow by downvoting questions that seem perhaps trivial to some StackOverflow residents.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is still currently 7 dimensions. Fingers crossed they will add support for more in the future.

https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/cuda-fortran-prog-guide/#cfpg-var-qual-attr-constant